# HTML video white balance editing

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I have a very simple app that streams a video from the webcam. I get the stream from the webcam by calling `getUserMedia` and adding it to an existing HTML video element's stream.

The point of the video is to take screenshots (by drawing it on a canvas element).

My question is: is there any way to manually modify video's white balance?
For now, I am working only on the latest Firefox, in case that matters.

This is a part of my code:

```
function handleSuccess(stream) {
  video.srcObject = stream;
  video.srcObject.getVideoTracks()[0].applyConstraints({
    whiteBalanceMode: 'shade',
    // or whiteBalanceMode: true,
  });

  console.log(video.srcObject.getVideoTracks()[0].getConstraints());
}

// console log does not show whiteBalanceMode included in the constraints
```

EDIT: I've found a css solution for this and I'm using jquery for simplicity.

```
    brightnessUp.onclick = function() {
      const bVal = $('#video1').css('-webkit-filter');
      const val = parseFloat(bVal.split('(')[1].split(')')[0]);
      const newVal = val + 0.1 < 7.1 ? val + 0.1 : 7;
      $('#video1').css('-webkit-filter', 'brightness(' + newVal + ')');
    }

    brightnessDown.onclick = function() {
      const bVal = $('#video1').css('-webkit-filter');
      const val = parseFloat(bVal.split('(')[1].split(')')[0]);
      const newVal = val - 0.1 > -0.1 ? val - 0.1 : 0;
      $('#video1').css('-webkit-filter', 'brightness(' + newVal + ')');
    }
```

Comment: You need to find the right math formula and apply it to each pixel of the video you will draw on a canvas element, you can also take advantage of SVG filters.

Comment: @dnmh I am currently also trying to turn off whiteBalance mode on a getUserMedia videoTrack. However, documentation seems to imply this is only possible for imageTracks. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @escapecharacter sorry for the late reply, yes, I've found the solution. Please see my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

When you run  `getUserMedia` , what is actually return is a  `MediaStream`  object. There are plenty of ways to turn on and off White Balance, or edit what balance mode you are using. For a full list of attributes, check out the [W3 object page.](https://www.w3.org/TR/image-capture/)

Comment: Please see my edit above. From what I can tell, `whiteBalanceMode` is not part of `MediaTrack`  (https://www.w3.org/TR/mediacapture-streams/#dom-mediatrackconstraintset) constraints and a `MediaStream` has only `video` and `audio` constraints. What am I missing?